# Normalization of the table in vba with logarithms

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a vba code that will normalize with logarithm my whole table. Values are imported from another software so if the value is less than 0.1 it is written in cell "<0.1". I want program to format that cells in "number" and divide them with 2, then logarithm all values with base 10 and write them in new sheet. This is what I came up with so far:

```
Sub normalizacija()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Unesite granice normalizacije", Title:="Granice", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If Rng Is Nothing Then
Else
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets.Add
i = 0
For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count - 1
    For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count - 1
    Cells(r, c).Activate
    If Cells(r, c).NumberFormat <> "0" Then
        Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "0"
        Cells(r, c).Value = Cells(r, c).Value / 2
    End If
    Cells(r, c).Value = Log(Cells(r, c).Value)
    Next c
Next r
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Debbuger says it is fine untill I try to divide cell value with 2 and after that I don't know if the rest of the code is working.

Thanks for help!
Marin

Answer (score 0):

After your `Set ws = Sheets.Add` you are on the **new** worksheet.  So all the code with `Cells(r, c)` refers to the empty new sheet.  You must re-Active the original sheet after the `Sheets.Add.`

Comment: Thank you, but I still get error 13, type mismatch when I get to the logarithm function.`Sheets(ASh).Cells(r, c).Value = Log(Sheets(ASh).Cells(r, c).Value) / Log(10#)` where ASh is my original sheet string name

Comment: @MarinRomic  This is telling us that some cell or cells contain **Text** rather than **Numbers** ................we can't divide **Text** by two or take the *Log()* of **Text**